# "node '0' has no position - problems with allocating node positions to 'node types' in networkX/Python

Tags: python, position, nodes, networkx

I'm trying to plot a graph using networkX.

I have defined the precise positions as:

```
pos={0:(40,100), 1:(50,100), 2:(45,80), 3:(55,80), 4:(50,60), 5:(50,40), 6:(50,20)}
```

I am then separating the nodes into two 'types', so let's say that nodes 0, 2, 4, 6 are **'type a'** and 1, 3, 5 are **'type b'**. I am appending them to the two different node lists using the append function. So now I have the two different node lists: **type_a** and **type_b** and can plot them - for example using:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=type_a, node_size=2000,node_shape="s", node_color='g', labels=exploit_node_labels, with_labels=True, alpha=1)
```

My problem is in being able to allocate the node positions to the node at the time that I allocate the node. How do I allocate 'pos' at the point of appending the nodes to the two different lists?

This approach gives me an error as follows:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=type_a, node_size=2000,node_shape="s", node_color='g', labels=exploit_node_labels, with_labels=True, alpha=1)
          File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 386, in draw_networkx_nodes
            raise nx.NetworkXError('Node %s has no position.'%e)

networkx.exception.NetworkXError: Node '0' has no position.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the nodes in your graph `G` are strings of numbers, i.e, `'0', '1','2'`... instead of integers `0,1,2`... However, you are defining the positions using `pos` using integers instead of strings. Try to define your positions as follows and it should work

```
pos={'0':(40,100), '1':(50,100), '2':(45,80), '3':(55,80), '4':(50,60), '5':(50,40), '6':(50,20)}
```